# RegEx 5 Strings to Match - Replace Based on Match

Tags: regex, replace

Angular/JS Application

I have this: `input.replace('/&lt;|&gt;|&quot;|&amp;|&apos;/gm', need this to be based on match value)`.

So I want to search by all those strings - but I want to replace the value based on which one matched. So if `&quot;` matches = replace with `"` and if `&gt;` matches = replace with `>`

I basically want to avoid this:

`input.replace('/&lt;/gm', <)`

`input.replace('&gt;/gm', >)`

`input.replace('&quot;', ")`

I think it has something to do with capturing groups - not a regex person.

Maybe the answer can only be:  `inputString.replace('/&lt;/gm', '<').replace('/&gt;/gm', '>').replace('/&quot;/gm', '"').replace('/&amp;/gm', '&').replace('/&apos;/gm', '\'');`

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "< if #1"? What does "#1" refer to?

Comment: @bgfvdu3w I want to search by all those strings - but I want to replace the value based on which one matched.  So if &quot; matches = replace with " and if &gt; matches = replace with >

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unescape HTML entities in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript)

Comment: @bgfvdu3w no I need to specifically match certain strings and replace them with corresponding values. I update the question - it might help.

Comment: Well, the strings you are trying to replace look like they are HTML entities. You're effectively trying to unescape/decode them. That's what I linked a solution to. Do you have other strings that are not HTML entities which need to be replaced too?

Comment: @bgfvdu3w they will only be the ones from above.  But I want to understand how I could do it with capturing groups (I think that's what it is called).  Not just how to encode them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's commonly done is to simply chain the replacements, executing one after another as in your example:

```js
input.replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/&gt;/g, ">").replace(/&quot;/g, '"').replace(/&amp;/g, "&").replace(/&apos;/g, "'")
```

the downside of this it that it really doesn't scale well: Each replace operation runs in linear time. Thus for m replacement and a string of length n, the time complexity will be O(n * m). If you now were to implement support for all 2k+ named HTML entities, this would quickly blow up and your performance would degrade severely - not to mention the O(m) garbage strings that are created in the process, making for O(n * m) garbage data.

The proper way is to create a *lookup table* (a hash table, called a *dictionary* in JS) with *O(1)* access with all the named entities and their replacements:

```js
const namedEntities = {lt: "<", gt: ">", quot: '"', amp: "&", apos: "'"}
return input.replace(/&(lt|gt|quot|amp|apos);/g, (_, match) => namedEntities[match])
```

this passes a replacement function to [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace); *no garbage strings are created* and the time complexity - assuming an ideal RegEx implementation - is O(n).

If you want to religiously follow DRY, you might want to build the RegEx from the keys:

```js
const regex = new RegExp("&(" + Object.keys(namedEntities).join("|") + ");", "g")
return input.replace(regex, (_, match) => namedEntities[match])
```

alternatively, consider using a more general RegEx, leveraging the dictionary to check whether an entity is valid and defaulting to no replacement:

```js
return input.replace(/&(.+?);/g, (entity, match) => namedEntities[match] || entity)
```

Comment: it didn't work for me - https://jsfiddle.net/37gufeva/1/

Comment: any reason you see that it's not working in the fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/37gufeva/1/

Comment: @RooksStrife: Strings are immutable, you must `return` the result of the call to `replace` (or overwrite `inputString`).